# permission confusion when trying to tail logs

Tags: linux, permissions, logs, chown

I would like to tail my radius logs with my user but I get the following:

```
ron@OldNotebook ~ [1]> sudo ls -l /var/log/radius/radius.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 radiusd radiusd 147918 Jun 22 15:04 /var/log/radius/radius.log
```

So the file belongs to radiusd

```
ron@OldNotebook ~> tail -f /var/log/radius/radius.log
tail: cannot open '/var/log/radius/radius.log' for reading: Permission denied        
tail: no files remaining
```

but I can look at it

```
ron@OldNotebook ~ [1]> groups
sys network scanner power radiusd rfkill users video storage optical lp audio wheel ron sudo
```

evewn though my user has been added to the radiusd group (with `usermod -aG radiusd ron`), I've changed the user of the directory too: `sudo chown radiusd:radiusd /var/log/radius/` and I have re-logged in with it as well. Can anyone give me a hint about what's going on here?

if you're wondering about the prompt, I'm using `fish`

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: @waltinator that helped to find me that the `/var/log/radius/` didn't have 755 but 700 instead. Thanks!